# Need to Insert Identity MasterId into 2 tables #tblUniqueKeys and #tblChild

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables "#tblData1" and "#tblData2" link with "Id" column. Table "#tblData2" may or may not data for the same "Id" of "#tblData1".

```
Create Table #tblData1 (Id int, Details VARCHAR(10),  UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
insert into #tblData1 values (1, 'DT1', 'uq1', '01/15/2016', 'abc'), (2, 'DT2', 'uq2', '01/16/2016', 'xyz');

Create Table #tblData2 (Id int, Details VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE);
insert into #tblData2 values (1, 'DT11', '01/16/2016'), (1, 'DT12', '01/17/2016')
```

Now, I need to insert data into below 3 tables "#tblUniqueKeys", "#tblMaster" and "#tblChild".

1. Same Identity "MasterId" into both tables "#tblUniqueKeys" and "#tblChild".
2. Data from  "#tblData1" into 2 tables "#tblUniqueKeys" and  "#tblMaster".
3. Data from "#tblData2" into table ""#tblChild".

   create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(101,1), Details VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
   create Table #tblUniqueKeys (UqId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE);
   create Table #tblChild (ChildId INT IDENTITY(201,1), MasterId INT, Details VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE);

Using below "Merge" sql query, I'm able to insert records into 2 table "#tblUniqueKeys" and  "#tblMaster".

**Question**, How to insert records into the 3rd table "#tblChild"? Can we insert record into 3rd table along with "MasterId" within same Merge query? Thanks!!!

```
MERGE INTO #tblMaster AS Dest
USING
(
SELECT UniqueKey, Details, DetectDate, UpdateBy
FROM #tblData1
) AS Src
ON (1 = 0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
(
Details
,DetectDate
,UpdateBy)
VALUES
(Src.Details
,Src.DetectDate
,Src.UpdateBy)
 OUTPUT inserted.MasterId, Src.UniqueKey, Src.DetectDate
 INTO #tblUniqueKeys(MasterId, UniqueKey, DetectDate);

select * from #tblMaster
select * from #tblUniqueKeys


DROP TABLE #tblData1;
drop table #tblData2;
DROP TABLE #tblMaster;
drop table #tblChild
DROP TABLE #tblUniqueKeys;
```

Comment: Well you don't really need to use a merge, you could just do separate insert statements.

Comment: Never Mind, I see you need a merge because you're outputing the source unique key, but an idea could be that rather than outputing directly into your #tblUniqueKeys, you output everything into a table variable. e.g. `declare @output TABLE (masterid int, uniquekey varchar(10), details varchar(10), detectdate varchar(10), updateby varchar(10)); .... output inserted.masterid, src.uniquekey, src.details, src.detectdate, src.updateby into @output;` then manipulate the data in the table variable as necessary.

Comment: thanks! I manage this insert